# Nearest Neighbour Algorithm?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, distance, nearest-neighbor

I keep getting an error when trying to execute my function. I think it is to due with calculating the distance between 2 coordinates. For example, [5,2] and [6,7], It isn't able to calculate the distance between these coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
import math
import copy

def calculate_distance(starting_x, starting_y, destination_x, destination_y):
    distance = math.hypot(destination_x - starting_x, destination_y - starting_y)  # calculates Euclidean distance (straight-line) distance between two points
    return distance

def nearest_neighbour_algorithm(selected_map):

  temp_map = copy.deepcopy(selected_map)
  optermised_map = [] 

  optermised_map.append(temp_map.pop()) 

  for x in range(len(temp_map)):
    nearest_value = 1000 
    neares_index = 0       
    for i in range(len(temp_map[x])):
      current_value = calculate_distance(*optermised_map[x], *temp_map[x])

      if nearest_value > current_value: 
        nearest_value = current_value 
        nearest_index = i 

    optermised_map.append(temp_map[nearest_index])
    del temp_map[nearest_index] 

  return optermised_map

copy_map = generate_map_1(200,200,5)
print("Map Points: ", copy_map)
print("Nearest Neighbour: ", nearest_neighbour_algorithm(copy_map))
```

The problem is here:

```
 current_value = calculate_distance(optermised_map[x] - temp_map[i])
```

I am trying to pass 2 coordinates to my calculate distance function but it doesn't allow me to as I get an error

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: program doesn't execute so I wouldn't know the results plus I am using random coordinates. the error I get is from the line I stated and the error code is :                      `current_value = calculate_distance(optermised_map[x] - temp_map[i])`

Comment: You've just identified several problems with the posting -- good going!  I'll wait until you've fixed them.

Comment: I have tried to reduce the code but this code is needed for you to understand what is going on. I am trying to find the shortest path between coordinates and then list them in the order of shortest path @Prune

Comment: why not using numpy?

Comment: is there any way of doing this without numpy? @Pygirl

Comment: Your posted code fails to run at all.  Satisfying two aspects of MRE does not make this a viable SO question.

Comment: it does run but I encounter an error code where it says my list index is out of range, and I wanted to know why I get this error code and is there a way to fix this. the error code I am getting occurs at this line of code:                                                          `for i in range(len(temp_map[x])):
      current_value = calculate_distance(*optermised_map[x], *temp_map[x])`

Comment: Again, please supply the expect MRE.  Supply the full error message.  Supply the code that produces that message.  Include your traces of the values that lead to the error.

Comment: After your changes, you made a typo. Change the argument *temp_map[x] to *temp_map[i] , when you call calculate_distance.
Btw if you followed what @Prune said, you would have seen all the errors from the start. That I call help.

Answer (score 0):

because you can't subtract list from another list

what exactly you want to do subtract each element of temp_map from optermised map ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is subtract coordinates from optermised map from temp map by passing the coordinates to the function `calculate_distance` . this will return a distance and will be stored in current value and it will loop this until it finds the shortest path. I hope this clears it up a bit

Comment: essentially I am trying to find the shortest distance between coordinates and list them in order